# Knockout and downloading csv/pdf

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, pdf, csv, knockout.js

I am using ASP.NET MVC and knockout.
I have a form to gather information.

The last field in the form, is the output type:
which can be HTML/CSV/PDF.

I have difficulties to output the result into CSV or PDF.
As knockout submit the form using ajax and ajax cannot save
the result into CSV or PDF.

If you have any idea, could you please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use knockout to create pdf. post your data to the server via ajax, and make asp.net create the pdf via C# from the server, and once the pdf is created, you can make it available to download.

Answer (score 1):

Use a form to post the data parameters to the server.

If you need to use parameters that are KO Observables or js variables, you can append them to the form using a js function like this:

```
 function downloadFile(idForm, parameters) {

            var id = '#' + idForm;

            $(id).submit(function () { //listen for submit event
                $(id + ' input').empty().remove();
                $.each(parameters, function (i, item) {
                    $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
                        .attr('name', item.name)
                        .attr('value', item.value)
                        .appendTo(id);
                });

                return true;
            });

            $(id).submit();
        };
```

You could pass an extra parameter indicating if you want to download a HTML, CSV or PDF file.